# Entity field query condition to match multi-value field

Tags: 7, entities

Using EFQ, I want to add a fieldCondition that has to match both values in a multi-value field (fixed at two values). The following doesn't seem to work:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
       ->entityCondition('bundle', 'node_type')
       ->fieldCondition('field_myfield', 'target_id', array(
          $id_1,
          $id_2
        ), '=');
```

This returns the error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand
>   should contain 1 column(s):

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
       ->entityCondition('bundle', 'node_type')
       ->fieldCondition('field_myfield', 'target_id', array(
          $id_1,
          $id_2
        ), 'IN');
```

For reference see https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-use-entityfieldquery-for-drupal-7